# unable to get user information after login

Tags: php, sql

The following page open only when user logged in

members.php

```
    <?php
require('includes/config.php');

//if not logged in redirect to login page
if (!$user->is_logged_in()) {
    header('Location: login.php');
}

//define page title
$title = 'Members Page';

//include header template
require('layout/header.php');
?>

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">
            <h2>Member only page - Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h2>
            <p><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></p>
            <hr>

        </div>
    </div>
        <?php
   // DATABASE INFORMATION
$server = '';
$database = '';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpassword = '';

//CONNECT TO DATABASE
$connect = mysql_connect("$server", "$dbuser", "$dbpassword")
    OR die(mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db("$database", $connect);
//ALWAYS ESCAPE STRINGS IF YOU HAVE RECEIVED THEM FROM USERS

$safe_username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
//FIND AND GET THE ROW
$getit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$safe_username'", $connect);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($getit);

//YOUR NEEDED VALUES
$bio1 = $row['active'];
$bio = $row['email'];
    ?>
```

### SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `memberID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `active` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `resetToken` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `resetComplete` varchar(3) DEFAULT 'No',
  PRIMARY KEY (`memberID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

here user name is stored in session

so i used second part of php to get user `email` and `active`

but i get following error

```
Internal Server Error
```

can someone help me whats wrong
after sucessfull login members.php should display user `email` from `SQL`

Comment: Does your table members have a column named ```id```?

This name is case-sensitive, so ```ID``` and ```Id``` is not the same as ```id```!

Comment: yes i have `memberID`

Comment: @SanojLawrence That's not the same

Answer (score 1):

This means the `ID` column does not exist in the table `members` are you sure you spelled everything right? Are you sure the database you're working in is called `members` as well? It seems weird to me that you name your database and table the same. **Also I noticed your session is called:`$_SESSION['username']` which makes me think it consists a string and the column is called id which makes me think that it's an integer**

**Conclusion:**

There is something wrong with your connection to mysql. We cant know what since we dont know what your table looks like. Steps to take:

1. Check if the column `id` exists
2. Check if the table you're working in is called: `members`
3. Check if the database you're working in is called: `members`
4. Make sure you actually compare the right value with the right column.

**Offtopic:**
No offense but
if you cant figure this error out by yourself, I would suggest you to actually study way more php

Comment: made changes to question

Comment: @SanojLawrence You shouldn't edit the question cause you have a different problem right now. You should keep the question you had before. Accept an answer(if the error is solved) and then make a new question about the new error.

Comment: thats the problem i had before `SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `ID`` after looking my sql its `memberID` and not `ID` when i replace i get the above error

Comment: @SanojLawrence Yes so I fixed your first error. Make another question for your other error. Accept an answer if it fixed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop Using mysql_ and move to mysqli_ or PDO
2. maybe change your mysql_numrows to mysql_num_rows.

   $num = mysql_num_rows($query) or die(mysql_error());

let me know the outcome.

couldn't put it in a comment.